# Can not obtain Telegram api_key

Tags: telegram

After reading [this](https://core.telegram.org/api/obtaining_api_id) Im trying to obtain a Telegram api_key using [this page](https://my.telegram.org/apps). The problem is that by submitting the page just say's: ERROR

No more information is provided. any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some days I tried again and everything was ok. Seems that it was a temporary problem in telegram api.